# C++ DirectX Multi-Colored Line

Tags: c++

I know a tiny bit of C++ and I want to make my own little game. I have figured out on how to draw a line, this is how it looks:

```
void DrawLine(int bx, int by, int bw, D3DCOLOR COLOR) 
{ 
    D3DRECT rec; 
    rec.x1 = bx - bw;//makes line longer/shorter going left 
    rec.y1 = by / by; 
    rec.x2 = bx + bw;//makes line longer/shorter going right 
    rec.y2 = by + 1;//makes line one pixel tall 
    d3ddev->Clear(1, &rec, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, COLOR, 0, 0); 

}
```

But I have a slight problem, I want to make the line to be rainbow colored like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to do that, if someone can point me in the right direction I would be glad! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve what you want, but I imagine that all of them are essentially an illusion.

You could, for instance, use the bitmap you linked to as a texture and map it to a long, thin rectangular mesh.

Another way would be to draw n line segments, each of a different color. Together, they would form a line looking kind of like what you want. You would, of course, need to figure out how to generate the colors by yourself, but the algorithm is probably pretty simple.

I would imagine that there are also solutions involving shaders.